# Draw a defined size circle around cursor in tkinter python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How can I draw a defined size circle around the cursor in tkinter python?

I tried

```
canvas.config(cursor='circle')
```

but it draws one particular circle and its size can't be changed.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a circle (on a canvas?), or are you asking how to get a cursor that includes both a pointer and a circle?

Comment: I need to get a circle around cursor when I move it (the same as the code above does, but be able to change the size), not just to draw a circle.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Motion` bind in Tkinter, which causes a function to activate each time the mouse is moved:

```
import tkinter as tk

global circle
circle = 0

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x + 3, event.y + 7  
    #the addition is just to center the oval around the center of the mouse
    #remove the the +3 and +7 if you want to center it around the point of the mouse

    global circle
    global canvas

    canvas.delete(circle)  #to refresh the circle each motion

    radius = 20  #change this for the size of your circle

    x_max = x + radius
    x_min = x - radius
    y_max = y + radius
    y_min = y - radius

    circle = canvas.create_oval(x_max, y_max, x_min, y_min, outline="black")

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Motion>", motion)

global canvas

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I wouldn't recommend using global variables generally, but for a simple program like this, it's okay.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I need! I'll try to add it to my big program.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw custom cursors. You have a very limited set of cursors to pick from.